# View video and use website simultaneously in same view with refreshes

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

So I am creating this interesting project. In this project, a you are guided through a website tour with a YouTube video. To achieve this I need to be able to view the video and work on the website simultaneously so that every page refresh doesn't load the video all over again and the user has his progress maintained.

Is there any jQuery plugin or library I could use? If someone knows anything related to this, please guide me ..

Thanks ..

Comment: Could you use an iframe? That way a user could navigate your site, but the page with the video won't reload.

Comment: Yea that's the objective, do you think iframes would work?

Comment: Absolutely, unless the website blocks `<iframe>`s in its headers, Google does this, but many sites do not. The only disadvantage is that if you wanted the video to be somehow incorporated into the webpage - rather than beside it or floating above - you would be unable to do that.